# how to subtract both array's [0] and [1] and so on

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays:

```
var array = [100,200,300,400];
var another = [50,100,150,200];
```

say I don't know how long the arrays are, but knows they are the same length. How do I subtract the respective elements?

Comment: what result do you want? the sum of arra - sum of another? or arra[0] - another[0]...arra[n] - another[n]?

Comment: Why don't you loop over the first array, and then inside the loop subtract that value from the value at the same index from the other array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array.map` like below

```js
var arra = [100, 200, 300, 400];
var another = [50, 100, 150, 200];

var diff = arra.map(function(v, i) {
  return v - another[i]
});

console.log(diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <script>
        var arra = [100, 200, 300, 400];
        var another = [50, 100, 150, 200];
        var diff = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arra.length; i++) {
            diff[i] = arra[i] - another[i];
            console.log(diff[i]);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Just subtract the respective positions.

Comment: You can omit all the HTML stuff.